# Create a "Colab notebook" using python

Tags: google-app-engine

look at the github link https://github.com/onpix/LCDPNet

I tried to do this but I really don't know

who can help me i thank you from the heart

Comment: What did you try? What is the error you get? You need to be specific about what your problem is